# model selection and model comparison

Tags: r, regression, model-selection, model-comparison, stepwise-regression

I have a question regarding to model comparison using multcomp for model comparison.

Suppose I have a linear model y~x1+x2+x3, and there are three levels in x1, say x1_l1, x1_l2 and x1_l3. I would like to test whether the outcome will be significantly different by different x1 levels. So I will use multcomp for pairwise comparison.

Now my question is, do I still need a stepwise model selection using stepAIC function? If needed, do I need to do stepAIC before multcomp (I think so, but need your confirmation)? And what if x1 goes away after stepAIC, can I say there is no statistical difference in outcome affected by x1?

Comment: Why do you think you need stepwise model selection at all?

Comment: In my case, I may have many independent variables, say x1 to x100. Having too many independent variables may overfit my data. Using stepwise selection seems commonly used in this scenario.